# Django custom save method

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have changed the save method to include a modified date field to changed on all saves. I want to know if I update the model using update() method. Will the save method be called??

Please answer explaining if not than how can I update the modified date field on all modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [read the documentation on the `update` method of a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) you will notice it says the following:

> Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save()).

but

> If you want to update a bunch of records for a model that has a custom save() method, loop over them and call save(), like this:

```
for e in Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010):
    e.comments_on = False
    # Or in your case, update the date here
    e.save()
```

Comment: Right! Also, remember that exists [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) and, also, [model util MonitorField](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils#monitorfield). Both approach avoid you overwrite save method.